# unable to run generated python (selenium) script from PHP

Tags: php, bash, python, selenium

I have an Ubuntu machine for headless selenium tests.

I generate a python script in /var/www/tmp/random123name.py via PHP and execute them. The script works when run from command line user, fails when run from web (apache www-data:www-data user).

The script recalls some system / python modules:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep, strftime
import os, json
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
```

This code returns 1:

```
$python = "sudo /usr/bin/python /var/www/tmp/random123name.py";
exec($python, $output, $return);
echo "OUT<pre>".print_r($output,1)."</pre>"; #returns empty
echo "RET<pre>".print_r($return,1)."</pre>"; #returns 1
```

I modified /etc/sudoers this way, without luck:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/python
```

I also tried

```
www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/python /var/www/tmp/
```

added www-data to dialout group and some other tries.
Thank you for your support.

Comment: Have you tried running the script from the command line as the www-data user? You can use su -s /bin/bash www-data to become the correct user.

Comment: What is in `$python`? Are you specifying the full path to your python interpreter and the full path the script? It might be that the command is not found.

Comment: Thank you guys for the replies. I tried to run the script and it doesnt work. $python = "sudo /usr/bin/python /var/www/tmp/random123name.py" (I update my question)

Comment: Have you tried calling `/usr/bin/sudo` rather than `sudo`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved: it's not enough to exit back to youruser / root, you need to exit ssh session and reopen it in order to load everything needed for visudo to work.

Answer (score 0):

As you yourself have figured out, changes to `sudoers` don't get applied to running sessions, only to new sessions. So you need to logout and login again to see it.

But much more importantly, you shouldn't need `sudo` for this purpose,
and allowing `www-data` user to run `python` as `root` without password is extremely scary. Surely there is a way to make your script work without needing `root` privileges, as a regular user, and I strongly urge you to try to figure that out, rather than resorting to `sudo` for this purpose.

Comment: luckily this VM is not exposed outside the LAN, but I'm willing to try any suggestion which would come, in order to have the lesson learned.